# How to plot ordered horizontal bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of values that I want to plot ordered in a horizontal bar plot with indices in y-axis and values in x-axis. This is the code I have, it outputs unordered bars.

```
        plt.barh(indices,values)
        plt.xlabel('Value', fontsize=12)
        plt.ylabel('Value Label', fontsize=12)
        plt.yticks(indices, listOflabels, rotation='horizontal')
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.title('horizontal ranked bar plot')
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do an `np.argsort` on `values`:

```
idx = np.argsort(values)
plt.barh(indices,values[idx])
plt.xlabel('Value', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Value Label', fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(indices, listOflabels[idx], rotation='horizontal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.title('horizontal ranked bar plot')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks the plot gets sorted but ```yticks``` outputs TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.

Comment: That means your `listOfLabels` is not an `np` list. Try: `np(listOflabels)[idx]` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I think you meant ```np.array(listOflabels)[idx]``` which works !